# app submission to app store with xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, submission

How is app submission to app store with Xcode 4 different from previous xcode versions? What happens once we click the submit button of Archives-organiser.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to click on validation, before that on itunesconnect we have to upload the binary and after that it will validate when we do validation, on Succesfully validation, click submit button and app will be submitted on app store

below is the link it will help you

http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2442

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no difference is the way Apple receives and evaluates your app. XCode 4 provides a different interface to submit apps (when compared to older versions).

See [How to submit apps in XCode 4](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2442) for more...